# Why color of the Border doesn't change?

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I have TextInput and it should be a border around it, when I'm trying to define the border color, it doesn't change, and just stay grey, why is that?

Here is the code which I use to render TextInput with border:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {
     StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TextInput,  AppRegistry
 } from 'react-native';

class Profile extends Component {

render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.profile}>
                   <View style={[styles.loginRow, {marginBottom: 8}]}>

                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInputValue}
                            ref={(ref) => this.password = ref}
                            onFocus={() => this.password.focus()}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                            placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
                            placeholder='Password'/>

                    </View>
            </View>
 );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

profile: {
        padding: 46,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#f0aa14'
    },

        loginRow: {
                height: 36,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderRadius:20,
                elevation: 1,
                marginBottom: 25

            },

        textInputValue: {
                flex: 1,
                alignSelf: 'center'

            }
    });


AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => Profile);
```

I expect that color of the border should be white, but it's grey, how to fix it?

[image]

This is what I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: can you add more of your code? To track down a UI issue it's very important to rebuild it and know exactly what's going on

Comment: @vanBrunneren just have added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with below style

```
loginRow: {
    height: 36,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 1,
    marginBottom: 25

},

textInputValue: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center'

}
```

What I did is, instead of `borderBottomWidth: 1,` for loginRow class, I have changed `borderWidth: 1,` and added `marginHorizontal: 20,` on textInputValue class.

Please check

Comment: One more small question, maybe you know, what should I change in  style, so the text would display exactly in the center of this rectangle?

Comment: just add `textAlign={"center"}` to your TextInput